# Accessing Angular element scope in User Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's assume you're writing a browser user-script (for Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey etc.) and you're customizing a web app implemented in Angular. Further, let's assume it serves you better to access its underlying data than to try and scrape it from HTML.

How do you access its Angular elements' scope to get the underlying properties?

For example:

```html
<ul id="my-list" ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <li>{{ row.fullName }}</li>
</ul>
```

and assume you want to get `row.firstName`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Angular element like this:

```js
const myListEl = document.getElementById('my-list')
const myList = angular.element(myList);
```

but `myList.scope()` will be undefined. You can call `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()` to fix it but that'll also reload the page. Instead, start your script with:

```js
// This is actually what angular.reloadWithDebugInfo() does:
window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO!" + window.name;
```

and it'll make `scope()` return the scope for the rest of the page's lifetime, so you can get e.g. `myList.scope().firstName`.